# How to reach the fuse box from Mk1 Golf Cabriolet?

Tags: electrical, golf

On an 91 Golf Cabriolet (Mk1), the fuse box is hidden behind the knee bar, and has no access hatch. I need to have a look at the top of the fuse box to see if fuse 19 (indicators) is broken.

Is there a way to reach the fuse box in a comfortable way?

Comment: For a lot of those early golfs it was easy just to drop the bottom half of the dashboard

Comment: @RoryAlsop - You should put this as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is definitely a flap which opens downwards and is accessible underneath the knee bar.  You may find it easier to squat down outside the car with the door open wide to access this flap.

**UPDATE**

My sincere apologies on this as I'd thought all Mk1 Golfs had the fuse box in the same location but on my 1985 Mk1 Golf Cabriolet, the fuse box is located on the passenger side of the scuttle panel under the bonnet.